# I am trying to get token from post method but I am getting json Response "Get/Method?Not Allowed" I using POST method for this

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift3, swift4

I am trying to POST email and passowrd and get token in response.

Using same token I have to get Response from server.

Please help me in this case I tried NSURL method and almofire  but didnt get proper outhput for the same.

```
//Check Below code and give me proper output.

func NewsAPI(){

    let url = "https://mastleadership.com/api/token-auth"
    //Get token logic
    let token = ""
    let headers = ["Authorization": "token \(token)"]
    let params = ["email": "kishor@kishor.com", "password":"abcd"] //This goes in the body of the request
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
        if let value = response.result.value {
            print(value)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood - you want to post request with params and receive token and again post the same request with the same params? Sorry but there is no logic in that.. But if really thats what you would like to do, than you have to make a request twice, and on response.result you have to save a proper response to your token variable.

Buut.. Anyway If you want to receive token as a response if params (login and password) are correct and than save it, than you could do it like this (Assuming the response from the server is also JSON):

Login request:

```
func loginRestt(login:String, password:String){
    let urlStr = "https://mastleadership.com/api/token-auth"
    let params = ["login":login, "password":password]
    let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Content-Type": "application/json"]

   Alamofire.request(urlStr, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            print("\(self.TAG), receiving response from login with \(response)")
            guard let receivedResponse = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.data!, options: []) as? [String:Any] else {
                print("\(self.TAG), Error parsing response from login for json")
                return
            }
            //Here I get token and save it to preferences
            if let token:String = receivedResponse["token"] as? String {
                print("\(self.TAG), \(token)")
                UserDefaults.standard.set(token, forKey: preferencesKeys.loginToken)
            } else {
                print("\(self.TAG), error receiving token")
                return
            }

        case .failure(let error):
            print("\(self.TAG), error receiving response for login with \(error)")
            return
        }
    }
}
```

And than for any other request that need token just add token in headers like in that example:

```
    let token = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: preferencesKeys.loginToken)
    let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Authorization": "token \(token!)"]
RestService.shared.almgr.request(urlStr, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
               //response received 
            case .failure(let error):
                //problems
            }
```